# display selectable drop down options based on a checkbox selection

Tags: forms, ajax, navigation

I am trying to create a form in Drupal. I want to create the following situation: if a  checkbox is selected I want to display a drop down menu. can you please suggest a way to do it.

Comment: Are you developing a custom module or do you need this feature on existing modules like the core node fields or some contrib module?

Comment: I needed this in a custom form. I am able to do it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Drupal form api states.

Example:

```
function example_form_states($form, &$form_state) {

  $form['click_me'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Click me!'),
  );

  $form['example_states'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'),
    '#options' => array(
      0 => t('Test 1'),
      1 => t('Test 2'),
     ),
    '#states' => array(
      'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="click_me"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
      ),
    ),
  );

  return $form;
}
```

**Additional Resources**
https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example!form_example_states.inc/function/form_example_states_form/7.x-1.x
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x#states

Answer (score 2):

**Programatic way**

```
  $form['checkbox_form'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('sometitle'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('checkbox_form', TRUE),
  );

  $form['selectbox'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('sometitle'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('selectbox'),
    '#options' => array(
          TRUE => t('Yes'),
          FALSE => t('No'),
     ),
    '#states' => array(
      'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="checkbox_form"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Second form element `visible` makes the trick.

**Module Way**

Use [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module.

> Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between
>   fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for
>   editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the
>   right condition. When editing a node (or any other entity type that
>   supports fields, like users and categories), the dependent fields are
>   dynamically modified with the States API. A simple use case would be
>   defining a custom “Article teaser" field that is shown only if a "Has
>   teaser" checkbox is checked, but much more complex options are
>   available.